# Fullcalendar v5 - Invalid date bug

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a seems-to-be-random bug with fullcalendar v5 on dayGridMonth.

Sometimes when I load/reload my page the dayGridMonth is full of "Invalid date" instead of the actual month grid

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZyn9.png)

My code looks like that :

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'fr',
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    firstDay: 1, // Monday
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    height: 'auto',
    events: currentCalendarEvents,
    eventOrder: 'eventId'
   });
```

'currentCalendarEvents' is an array I retrieve from an AJAX request, the event array is well populated when I print it in the console, even when I have the "Invalid date"

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] of the issue including sample data. What you've posted above would not, by itself, cause this problem. If we have enough code/data to be able to see the issue then we can hopefully suggest a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Do you set initialdate after initialization (the code you have shown to us)?